# Javascript to get two parents up (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, parent, target

I've got:

```
<div id='someId'>
    <div>
        <div onclick='someFunction(event)'>
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

someFunction(event){
    var twoParentsUpId = ??????
}
```

How can I get this "someId" with the other two DIVs not having any IDs?

... not using jQuery.

Comment: `this.parentNode.parentNode`?

Comment: `event.target.parentElement.parentElement`

Comment: remarkable how much negativity the users of this site store - that is, downvoting a question by a man who doesn't know the keyword and whom Google didn't help

Comment: Your question "does not show any research effort" says the tooltip text of DV button. Searching for your partial title gives [a lot of good results](https://www.google.fi/search?q=javascript+get+parents&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=yKKWVpSxDcSzswHe5p-gDg). Also you can see links to related SO posts on the right side of the page. These (and probably more) were shown you when you wrote your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it for you https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/jaer6zzd/

```
<div id='someId'>
    <div>
        <div onclick='someFunction(event)'>
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function someFunction(event){
    var twoParentsUpId = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
    twoParentsUpId.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```